# Returning Query from PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, recursive-query

I have a list of records which has employee ids for each employee (emp_id), and their manager's employee id (manager_id)

Lets say I wanted to run a query to get all columns for the entire chain of command for Sandrine (emp_id = 63679) (i.e. Sandrine, Sandrine's boss, Sandrine's boss's boss, etc.)

How would I write this query?

I tried the following loop in PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getpersons() RETURNS SETOF person
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$ Declare
counter INTEGER := 63679 ;
Begin
WHILE (Counter is not null) loop
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.emp_id = Counter);
Counter = employees.manager_id;
END LOOP;
END; $$
SELECT * from person;
```

the db looks like this:

[image: SQL Exercise Dataset]

Comment: You probably want to use a recursive common table expression (CTE).  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html.  Scroll down to see an example getting parts/sub-parts of a product.  A management hierarchy is a similar tree structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has several errors.

1. you are selecting from a table named `employees`, so the function should return `setof employees`, not "person"
2. You don't store the result of the select anywhere, so you can't actually assign the "counter" variable (which is a really bad choice for a variable name)
3. `execute` is only needed for dynamic SQL, not if you have static SQL
4. you should pass the ID of the employee to start with as a parameter, rather than hard coding it.

So in order to actually use the row you retrieved you need to store it in a variable, which can be defined as the same type as the resulting table.

Putting all of that together, your function should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getpersons(p_startid integer) 
  RETURNS SETOF employee
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$ Declare
  l_id INTEGER := p_startid;
  l_row employee;
Begin
  WHILE (l_id is not null) loop
    SELECT * 
      into l_row
    FROM employee 
    WHERE emp_id = l_id;

    l_id := l_row.manager_id;
    return next l_row;
  END LOOP;
END; 
$$
;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select *
from getpersons(63679);
```

---

However, it is not needed to write a function to traverse such a hierarchy. This can be done with a single SQL statement using a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
with recursive persons as (
  select *
  from employees
  where id = 63679 
  union all 
  select ch.*
  from employees ch
    join persons p on p.manager_id = ch.id
)
select *
from persons;
```